# javascript edge detection on a video blob

Tags: javascript, opencv, video, blob, edge-detection

I'm trying to record a video from a webcam, then to apply an edge detection filter to this video using openCV.js (properly included in my html file). The recording works, I'm doing it with WebRTC. It gives me a video in a blob, and I can display it without any issue.

Here is the code for edge detection function :

```js
async function detectContours(inputBlob) {
    console.trace("a");

    const response = await fetch(URL.createObjectURL(inputBlob));
    const blob = await response.blob();

    const inputVideo = document.createElement("video");
    inputVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
    inputVideo.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
        resolve();
    });
    inputVideo.load();
    });

    console.log("type de inputVideo : %o", typeof inputVideo);
    console.log("vidéo d'entrée : %o * %o", inputVideo.height, inputVideo.width);

    console.trace("b");
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
    inputVideo.addEventListener("canplaythrough", () => {
        resolve();
    });
    inputVideo.load();
    });
    await inputVideo.play();

    console.trace("c");
    const outputCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    outputCanvas.width = inputVideo.videoWidth;
    outputCanvas.height = inputVideo.videoHeight;
    const outputCtx = outputCanvas.getContext("2d");

    console.trace("d");
    outputCtx.drawImage(
        inputVideo,
        0,
        0,
        outputCanvas.width,
        outputCanvas.height
    );

    console.trace("e");
    const cvInput = cv.imread(outputCanvas);
    const cvOutput = new cv.Mat();

    console.trace("f");
    cv.Canny(cvInput, cvOutput, 100, 200);

    console.trace("g");
    console.log(
      "vidéo d'entrée : %o * %o",
        inputVideo.videoHeight,
        inputVideo.videoWidth
    );
    console.log("canvas de sortie : %o * %o", cvOutput.rows, cvOutput.cols);
    console.log("%o bytes", cvOutput.data.length);
    const outputImageData = new ImageData(
        new Uint8ClampedArray(cvOutput.data),
        cvOutput.cols,
        cvOutput.rows / 4
    );

    console.trace("h");
    const outputCanvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
    outputCanvas2.width = outputImageData.width;
    outputCanvas2.height = outputImageData.height;
    const outputCtx2 = outputCanvas2.getContext("2d");
    outputCtx2.putImageData(outputImageData, 0, 0);

    console.trace("i");
    const outputBlob = await new Promise((resolve) =>
        outputCanvas2.toBlob(resolve, "image/png")
    );

    console.trace("j");
    URLvideoEdge = URL.createObjectURL(outputBlob);
    blobVideoEdge = outputBlob;

    console.trace("k");
}
```

Here is the code of the function called when I click on my "stop recording" button :

```js
async function stopRecording() {
    console.trace("1");
    //Recording the video
    for (let track of stream.getTracks()) {
        track.stop(); //when this event is triggered, function called display the video without any issue 
    }
    console.trace("2");

    // verifying blobVideoCouleur actually is an object
    while (typeof blobVideoCouleur !== "object") {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100)); // Pause 100ms
    }

    console.trace("3");


    //Applying edge detection filter
    await detectContours(blobVideoCouleur);

    console.trace("4");


    //Displaying filtered video 
    playBack.src = URLvideoEdge;
    playBack.autoplay = true;

    console.trace("5");

}
```

`playBack` is a global var defined as the html video element playing the recorded video

Just in case, here is the function doing this, called when I stop recording :

```js
    recorder.onstop = () => { // Event triggered when I stop the recorder 
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { //
        type: 'video/webm' // Et il le fait en webm
        })
        chunks = [];
        URLvideoCouleur = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        playBack = document.getElementById("playBack");
        playBack.src = URLvideoCouleur;
        playBack.controls = true;
        blobVideoCouleur = blob;
    }
```

well I go through many issues using openCV.js as I never used it before, so it's why there is that much `console.trace` in my code, as I could see where the code had bugs. The last "solution" I found in this code was to make a division by 4 here :

```js
    const outputImageData = new ImageData(
        new Uint8ClampedArray(cvOutput.data),
        cvOutput.cols,
        cvOutput.rows / 4
    );
```

Cause ImageData was looking for datas length equal to in_video_height*in_video_width*4 cause of dimensions multiplied by 4 "colours" (RGBA) but in facts I juste have one layer, in black or white, after applying a edge detection filter.

So from now on, the code run without interruptions or error in console, but the final behavior is not as expected. My video player don't show filtred video instead of "normal" video, it's not even a video but a black block, with controls, but useless cause the video have a duration of 0s. (see screen)
[what's shown instead of my filtered video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDg9O.png)

Well... As I don't have console feed back, I'm just stuck, i no longer have any idea of what I can do to have this filtered video. Do you have some suggestion ?
Moreover, I can't avoid to think this function `detectContours` is a huge gasworks, there isn't a simpler way to apply an edge detection filter to my video in js ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible to provide minimal but reproducible code that shows your issue? [ask]

Answer (score 0):

As I can't put code into a comment of my question to answer to @Markus, I'm using an answer. Moreover I think it's quite pertinent as I worked on my code since yesterday, and many things evolved.

So I immersed myself into openCV.js's datasheet, and it led me to write a short and working function to apply an edge detection filter (EDF) on a single image :

```js
function detectContour(){
    //Apply an edge detection filter to a single image
    //Getting the matrice from an <img>
    let matriceCouleur= cv.imread("imageSource"); // "imageSource" =  id of an <img> in html
    let matriceGris = new cv.Mat(); 
    let matriceEdge = new cv.Mat(); 
    cv.cvtColor(matriceCouleur, matriceGris, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY); 
    cv.imshow("canvasGris", matriceGris);
    cv.Canny(matriceGris, matriceEdge, 50, 100, 3, false);
    cv.imshow("canvasEdge", matriceEdge);
}
```

(I'm not traducing my var, i feer i'll do some mistakes and then the names will not match here.)

I don't kept the page in datasheet I used to get this. :( but it solves 2 of my issues : clearer cause shorter (= way better), and it works.

Now, I've adapt this for a video. Once again, [there is an answer](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d00/tutorial_js_video_display.html) into the datasheet :

```js
let video = document.getElementById('videoInput');
let src = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let dst = new cv.Mat(video.height, video.width, cv.CV_8UC4);
let cap = new cv.VideoCapture(video);
console.log(typeof cap);

const FPS = 60;
function processVideo() {
    try {
        if (!streaming) {
            // clean and stop.
            src.delete();
            dst.delete();
            return;
        }
        let begin = Date.now();
        // start processing.
        cap.read(src);
        cv.cvtColor(src, dst, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
        cv.Canny(dst, dst, 50, 100, 3, false);
        cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dst);
        // schedule the next one.
        let delay = 1000/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
        setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
    } catch (err) {
        utils.printError(err);
    }
};
```

It works well in the sandbox of the page. Unfortunately, it works with a livestream, and I've to work with a finished video recorded from cam. So I've to adapt it. Here is my code (not all, 'cause other parts are working as I worked on it before, so I don't want to flood with useless code, only necessary lines for "minimal but reproducible code", I understood. :) )

```js
/* globales variables */
//...
let matSrc;
let matDst;
let captur;
let traitement;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', demarrerApp); //Waiting for all elements to be loaded

function demarrerApp(){ // make the app works properly after all html elements are loaded
    initialise_variables(); // Initialize global variables
    cameraShow(); // Launch the webcam
}

function initialise_variables(){
    //...
}

function cameraShow()
{
    //...
}

function startRecording() // called on a button
{
    //...
}

async function stopRecording() { // called on a button
    //...
    traitement = document.getElementById("videoToTreat"); // id verified : no problem
    traitement.src = URLvideoColor; // URL get after I record the cam and close it. the video is playing well
    matSrc = new cv.Mat(traitement.videoHeight, traitement.videoWidth, cv.CV_8UC4);
    matDst = new cv.Mat(traitement.videoHeight, traitement.videoWidth, cv.CV_8UC1);
    captur = cv.VideoCapture(traitement); // tracking the video to treat with the object captur : affectation made with cv.VideoCapture(string video_to_treat)
    console.log(typeof captur); // answer : undefined. Normal ?
    detectContourVideo(); // Call the filtering function
}

function detectContourVideo(){
    captur.read(matSrc); /*objective : catch current frame of the video and put it in matSrc.
    Error : "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'read')" so it don't work cause captur is undefined... But I defined it as a global variable and initialized it right before to call the function :(
    //... next lines useless as the first one don't even work. :(

}
```

So, if I understood the datasheet, I should have `typeof captur = object`, shouldn't I ? I can't identify my mistake by myself.
Using an `await` in the line `captur = await cv.VideoCapture(traitement);` don't change the behavior of the page. But I'm pretty sure `VideoCapture` do not return a promise, so it's predictable.
Doing a loop to wait `typeof captur == object` just lead to an infinite loop. So I guess `typeof captur` will not change with time.
Using a local video loaded directly with html page, istead of a camera rec associated with js to a  don't solve the issue.
What else can I try ?
thanks